# jQuery Mobile - undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

So I am working on this app, where you could see a list of animals, then click on one item from the list and app would bring you into another screen, where you would be able to see for example a photo and a brief description about the animal (all data is from JSON file.)

However I am getting this issue with the description section, I keep getting "undefined" whenever I want to display animalDescription under the animalPicUrl

Here are my javascript functions

```
function generateAnimalLink(animal){
  return '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)'
        + '" onclick="goToAnimalDetailPage(\''
        + animal.name 
        + '\',\''
        + animal.picUrl +'\')">'
        + animal.name + '<br> <p>'
        + animal.description + '</br> </p>'
        + '</a></li>';
 }
 function goToAnimalDetailPage(animalName, animalPicUrl, animalDescription){


  var animalPage = $("<div data-role='page' data-url=fakeUrl><div data-role='header'><h1>"
                  + animalName + "</h1></div><div data-role='content'><img border='0' src='" 
                  + animalPicUrl + "' width=20% height=20%></img></div><div data-role='content'><h4>"
                  + animalDescription "</h4></div><div data-role='footer'><h4>" 
                  + "</h4></div><a data-role='button' data-rel='back'>Back</a></div>");
```

Comment: + ((animalDescription == undefined)?"": animalDescription )+

Comment: @user666 description must be loaded from the json file, all this gives me is undefined :(

Comment: Then describe full task in your question. The solution to avoid undefined exception is to check if your variable equals undefined. But if your problem  is undefined value itself, then check your path to that value in the json tree.

Comment: I would use jQuery objects then pure html... like var a = $("<a></a>"); a.html(animal.name + "<br/>"+animal.description); a.attr("title",animal.description); a.click(function(){ var animalPage="<div>"+ $(this).attr("title") + "</div>"; }); $("#yourelementtoappendto").append(a);

Comment: All sorted. Many thanks.